# How to Mark 0 line for X axis and Y axis in MSChart c#

Tags: mschart, gridlines

I have implemented a MsChart which displays the values properly. Everything is running fine. My problem is i need to highlight grid line for 0 on X axis and 0 on Y axis. all other grid lines will be in different color other than there 2. Please suggest Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.
if someone need reference here it is:
Area.axisX.Linecolor =  color.Red;